# sql query performing filtered summation and total summation and a division of the two in the same line

Tags: sql

I am trying to perform a query that should not be too hard but I am not very competent in sql.

Assume this table:

```
Type  |  WINS    | 
-----------------
  A   |   100    |
  A   |   200    |
  B   |   100    |
  B   |    50    |
```

and I need a table that shows the WINS for type A, the total WINS and then divides the two.
The queries that do that independently are simple:

```
select sum(t.WINS) from t -- result is 450
select sum(t.WINS) from t where t.type = A -- result is 300
```

So, the division should be the filtered summation over the total summation *100 and the resulting table would look like:

```
WINS_FILTER  |  WINS_TOTAL  | PERCENTAGE %
----------------------------------------
   300       |     450      |    66.67. -- results of 300 *100 / 450
```

Is there a way to perform it? I tried a self join or a join with the filtered table, but did not work out.

Comment: Use a `case` _expression_ to do _conditional aggregation_.

Comment: Which DMS you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `CASE Expression` using conditional aggregation [as in this demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/233f94/1)

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'A' THEN WINS ELSE 0 END) AS WINS_FILTER,
    SUM(WINS) AS WINS_TOTAL,
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'A' THEN WINS ELSE 0 END) * 100.0 / SUM(WINS), 2) AS PERCENTAGE
FROM 
    my_table;
```

Output :

| WINS_FILTER | WINS_TOTAL | PERCENTAGE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 300 | 450 | 66.67 |

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sum(case ...` for this:

```
select
    sum(case when t.type = 'A' then t.WINS else 0 end) WINS_FILTER,
    sum(t.WINS) WINS_TOTAL,
    sum(case when t.type = 'A' then t.WINS else 0 end) / sum(t.WINS) PERCENT
from t
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with something like this because it gives me any case (unless I also narrow down the filter):

```
select  distinct t.type
        , sum(t.WINS) over (partition by t.type) as FILTERED
        , sum(t.WINS) over () as TOTAL
        , round(sum(t.WINS) over (partition by t.type) * 100 / sum(t.WINS) over (), 2) as PERCENTAGE
from TABLE t
-- where t.type = 'A'
order by t.type
```